# Reloading a page after an event has finished

Tags: javascript, php, audio, onclick

> EDIT : This is now solved, thanks very much everyone who replied. I
>   will come back here and vote up replies when I have enough reputation
>   to do so :)

I have been trying to figure out how to reload the page after an onclick audio file has finished playing.

I have made a static page with an image covering the entire window. I have a bunch of silly audio files in a folder called "audio"

I have some php code in place that will pick a random mp3 in the audio folder and echo its filename on request:

```
$files = glob('audio/*.mp3');  // get all .mp3 files in the music directory
$fname = $files[array_rand($files)]; // get a random file name
//echo $fname; // uncomment to echo random file name
```

And later in the page some JavaScript to play a file when a mouse click is detected with the randomly generated file name injected into the code :

```
<script>
    function play(){
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
                }
    </script>
    <input type="image" SRC="eye.gif" value="PLAY"  onclick="play();setTimeout('history.go(0);',6000);l">
    <audio id="audio" src="<?php echo $fname; ?>" ></audio>
```

At the moment, I have a couple of onclick events happening however, I am not happy with this one:

```
setTimeout('history.go(0);',6000);l
```

The timeout is a workaround, where I am gambling that the audio file would have finished playing before the refresh commences after the time threshold is met.

What I would really like, is some way of detecting when the file has finished playing in the browser, and then refresh the page automatically.

(I am refreshing the page so the random audio file gets generated again.)

I hope my post makes sense!

Any help here would be greatly appreciated from the experts on this site!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-read your question, and it seems like you just want to loop different audio tracks randomly, so no refresh required. In this case, there's no reason to call PHP back, just give JavaScript all the file links, and let it do its work.

```
<script>
var songs = <?php echo json_encode(glob('audio/*.mp3')); ?>;

function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
        audio.src = songs[Math.floor(Math.random()*songs.length)];
        audio.load();
    }, false);
    audio.play();
}
</script>
<input type="image" SRC="eye.gif" value="PLAY"  onclick="play();">
<audio id="audio" src="<?php echo $fname; ?>" ></audio>
```

**Old answer:**

There are listeners that you can attach onto your audio:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    history.go(0);
}, false);

audio.play();
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it works well! thanks! :)

Audio no longer cuts off before it has finished, and the page refreshes (I have removed my onclick refresh event thanks to your code!)

The only thing that seems strange, and it is probably more browser behaviour than anything, is the delay of the audio finishing to the page refreshing is seemingly a second or more.

Either way, you have hit my original objective. :)

Comment: Thanks for your updated code! Awesome, thanks!

I added it in, however for some reason no audio is being played. Trying to figure it out, but I'm a bit of a noob!

Comment: Oops, my fault. I forgot to add "echo" for echo json_encode.

Comment: Wow, now I see what the echo does in the source! Nice! I like it!

Half the reason of using php was to avoid having to hard code file names into the source.

Thanks very much!

There is one small problem... it now plays one audio file after the other. 

The onclick works to initiate it, however it just goes through all the tracks one by one without stopping. It is still random though ;)

Comment: I figured it out!

I just removed the first `audio.play();` as it was in the script twice, and it waits for the user input again!

Thankyouuuuu! :)

Comment: I can see what you were going for. An eye, that plays music, when you click on it. Pretty cool idea.

Comment: That was just a test. Clickable random audio bits. The eye was just so I didn't get too bored looking at the page while working on it. The audio was just for testing too. I noticed my encoder made all the files either 4 or 11 seconds long. Pretty useless! :)

Eventually I plan for a version of this idea to be an error 404  page with easter eggs. :D

Thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a callback fn that reloads the page on `canplaythrough` event:

`audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', isAppLoaded, false);`

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this to work, however it is likely cos I am not very good at this :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reloading the page. I'd suggest using a callback in the play() function to call a second function, the second function could use Ajax to get another response from the php script and drop it into the src, then call the play function again

I'm using my mobile phone right now so a bit hard to write an example, but if nobody jumps on it I'll give it a go later on.

Hope that helps a bit  If you're unsure about Ajax have a look on w3schools, their tutorials are very good

---

**edit:**
Here is a suitable script, untested so keep an eye out for syntax, but even if it's not quite working it should put you strongly in the right direction

```
function playRandomAudio() {
    // get random audio
    $.ajax({url: "randomaudio.php", success: function(result){
        $("#audio").attr("src",result);
    }});

    // play it
    $("#audio").play();
}

$(function() {
    // document onload, play audio
    playRandomAudio();
});

$("#audio").bind('ended', function(){
    // done playing, do it again 
    playRandomAudio();
});
```

randomaudio.php

```
<?php
$files = glob('audio/*.mp3');  // get all .mp3 files in the music directory
$fname = $files[array_rand($files)]; // get a random file name
echo $fname; // uncomment to echo random file name
```

To improve robustness, I'd encourage a try/catch around the 3 lines of php allowing you to return a nice fail rather than worrying about potential nonsense coming through or invalid files that could produce unexpected results on the javascript side. Then the ajax call could have a failure section that could do some other task such as an alert

Don't forget to include jquery https://code.jquery.com/

Further reading on jquery/ajax if you are not experienced in using these http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Ah I really like this idea, much better than a full refresh.

Comment: Someone has answered my question above, however your solution of refreshing the php rather than the whole page does sound like a better way of tackling things than I had planned it.

Side note : I'm new here, so I don't know whether I should mark the solution given above as correct, or if I am allowed to wait for your method? Can 2 things be marked as the answer?

Comment: Hi Darren,
I appreciate your write up, however It doesn't seem to work for me.

Am I putting this code between <script> tags in the body? Does it still require <?php tags too?

If not, that must be where I am going wrong.

It seems the way I am trying to do it results in no filename being injected into my onclick event 

I have a feeling it might be because my call to echo $fname is now in another file and isn't loading?

Comment: Ah wait. jquery. Didn't include that. Never done it before. Why do I need that?

To be honest, I didn't follow a lot of what you just said. I don't mind looking it up, but jumping in on a site without knowing what I am looking for is a bit awkward.

It seems that multiple technologies might need to be used in this page:

HTML, PHP, Javascript, CSS... and now ajax and jquery? I got to be honest,  don't really know what I am doing all of a sudden!

Comment: I have included jquery in the head now :

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Something is still broke with the injection.

Reading the Ajax page you sent me... Wish me luck!

Comment: JQuery is best summarised by its tagline "code less, do more". It's essentially just an extension of JavaScript that allows you to do complicated things in much simpler ways. Doing Ajax requests and modifying properties of html tags on the fly are two very common usages. Anything that is done In jQuery can also be done in basic JavaScript, but often the JavaScript ends up far more complex, just including the jQuery script as you've successfully done will allow you to do it the easier way!

Comment: You might want to get the jQuery to output the value of the Ajax request in an alert to check it's responding as expected. You want it to just output the filename and nothing else